# Tried everything to get Windows Installer working. Any options beyond?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, windows-installer

I am trying to fix a client's computer and the Windows installer is shot. I've tried EVERYTHING I can find on the internet. Nothing's worked yet.

I have tried:

- System Restore — Failed, and even deleted the earlier points due to corruption
- `sfc /scannow` — shows corrupted files, but does nothing to fix
- Booted from the install CD to repair, and didn't find any issues
- `chkdsk /f` — still nothing
- `net start msiservice` — yields a cannot start, and no errors.
- registered the service and unregistered and reregistered — still no help
- I tried something via Microsoft's site having to do with attributes, permissions, I believe. But it was related to `dllcache`, which I saw doesn't exist in Windows 7, so that one's out.

Is there even anything else to do at this point?

Comment: Update the Windows Installer?

Comment: Beyond EVERYTHING there's nothing you can do.

Comment: yep, easier fix was a wipe and re-install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Before doing anything else, make sure all the data is backed up, and verify that you can restore from the backup.)

Here are a few things you can try:

1. Try a different installation CD to rule out corrupt media.
2. If it still fails, then run a fresh installation (sometimes a Windows environment can be so badly corrupted that a new installation is the faster and simpler solution).
3. If that fails, then you have a hardware problem.
4. Update the BIOS and try again as a last resort before swapping hardware (start with the hard drive).

Comment: Yea, I was afraid of that. Guess I'll start the backup! Thanks ya'll!